# socket.io redis store on openshift

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, store, openshift

I'm trying to set up socket.io on node.js to use redisstore so i can comunicate with pubsub with multiple node on the opeshift platform, but i can't manage to connect to the redis server. I'm using [this cartridge](https://github.com/smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart).
I tried to connect with

```
var pub    = redis.createClient(process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PORT,
                                process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_HOST);
```

but it doesn't work (and I found out why: [createClient() only accept IP addresses](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1283)) and it fallback to the default port and host, then I ran **rhc port-forward**:

```
$ rhc port-forward appname
Checking available ports ... done
Forwarding ports ...
Address already in use - bind(2) while forwarding port 8080. Trying local port 8081

To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address

Service         Local                OpenShift
--------------- --------------- ---- ----------------------------------------------
haproxy         127.0.0.1:8080   =>  127.5.149.130:8080
haproxy         127.0.0.1:8081   =>  127.5.149.131:8080
s_redis_db_host 127.0.0.1:54151  =>  blabla.appname.rhcloud.com:54151

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

So I tought I was doing all wrong and I had to set just the port like this:

```
var pub = redis.createClient(process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PORT);
```

but all I get is this

```
info: socket.io started
events.js:72
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
           ^
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:54151 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
 at RedisClient.on_error (/var/lib/openshift/532c3790e0b8cd9bb000006b/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:149:24)
 at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/532c3790e0b8cd9bb000006b/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/redis/index.js:83:14)
 at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
 at net.js:426:14
 at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
 DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
```

I tried to connect via

```
telnet $OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_HOST $OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PORT
```

And it works fine... Do you have any suggestions? Am I doing it wrong? (I'm still new to redis and socket.io)
(I omitted the rest of the code 'cause I know it works, I have no problem on my local machine, I just can't get the connection...)
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't work (and I found out why: createClient() only accept IP addresses) and it fallback to the default port and host

It does support Host, **[createClient](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/blob/master/index.js#L1189)** uses [`net.createConnection(port, host);`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_port_host_connectlistener) that does support hostname.

The following code will help you find the issue:

```
console.log(process.env);
var pub    = redis.createClient(process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PORT,
                                process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_HOST, {auth_pass: process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PASSWORD});
pub.on('error', console.log.bind(console));
pub.on('ready', console.log.bind(console, 'redis ready'));
```

Does your openshift Redis instance requires `AUTH` ?

Comment: it gives me the same error (plus all the env variables)... I don't know if requires auth (I guess so, because there's a password), anyway it doesn't work either with pub.auth(process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PASSWORD) and the error is the same. If I use process.env.OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST it tries to connect with the default host and port (127.0.0.1, 6379), while using just process.env.OPENSHIFT_DB_PORT connect to 127.0.0.1, 54151 and that should be ok because of the port forwarding... but nothing, just the same connection failed

Comment: Did the env variables contained "OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_PORT" and "OPENSHIFT_REDIS_DB_HOST" with the right value ? I updated the answer for AUTH support. If you connect with telnet to 127.0.0.1 54151 does it work? (it should).

Comment: they have the right values and i can't connect with telnet... i guess it's an openshift problem (or more probably the redis cartridge).. but it's really odd

Comment: Ok, since it's related with openshift I won't be able to help you any further :s. However I can say that once it's resolved on OpenShift the above provided code will work.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it is about a recent change on openshift, but i think the problem is in the variables. Although they work for telnet.

you can try this

```
var redisHost = process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_HOST;
var redisPort = process.env.OPENSHIFT_REDIS_PORT;
var redisPass = process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD;

var client = redis.createClient( redisPort, redisHost );
client.auth( redisPass );
```